# Upload file to Google Translator for translation

Tags: python, selenium

I know that I can use `googletrans` for text translation. However I have some files I would like to translate. So instead of uploading each one by hand I have decided to try it with python+selenium.

Here is my current code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://translate.google.com/")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/label").send_keys("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\file.pdf")
```

It is able to navigate to page but fails at upload stage. Is there any chance to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below code -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
action = ActionChains(driver)


driver.get("https://translate.google.co.in/")

Document_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Documents']")
Document_btn.click()
time.sleep(2)

Browse_Btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tlid-file-input']")
Browse_Btn.send_keys('Your Full File Path')
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Translate']").click()
```

Comment: hi , i am trying same way to convert pdf in tamil to english but it is failing. Could you help in this.

Comment: @NishaJha. Please share your code you have tried till now and let us know where you are facing issues/problem. Will definitely try to help.